# Incorrect vectorization from a raster in ArcGis (ArcScan)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polyline-creation, vectorization, arcscan

I am trying to make a vectorization to get lines from a raster image using arcscan. I saw some users making it but using easier images with more visible lines but is not working with my image. could somebody suggest some tool or process?

[image]

Comment: Have you read the document linked below to see if you have used all the settings / functionality in the toolbar? http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/pdf/arcscan-tutorial.pdf

Comment: how should we get free arc scan licence

Answer (score 1):

maybe I get !! the quality of my raster image is fundamental. I had some steps to process it, raster to polygon, buffer + to involve some internal parts, buffer - to eliminate some external parts, polygon to raster ...

[image]